# Integration Problem in react typescript, error in enum

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, integration, react-typescript

i am making an integration in a typescript application open source known as typebot.io https://github.com/baptisteArno/typebot.io/tree/main, i am facing a problem in integration, currently i am getting this error

so according to the contribution file we have created our folder in the given path with three file schema, constant, index.ts and we have given the variable in the integerationblocktype enum function in the constant.ts and i have put the schema function in the schema.ts that was global also initilized the path in global index.ts and this is the initial test file i created

```
import test from '@playwright/test';
import { createTypebots } from '@typebot.io/lib/playwright/databaseActions';
import { parseDefaultGroupWithBlock } from '@typebot.io/lib/playwright/databaseHelpers';
import { createId } from '@paralleldrive/cuid2';
import { IntegrationBlockType } from '@typebot.io/schemas/features/blocks/integrations/constants';

test.describe('Google Calendar block', () => {
  test('its configuration should work', async ({ page }) => {
    const typebotId = createId();
    await createTypebots([
      {
        id: typebotId,
        ...parseDefaultGroupWithBlock({
            type: IntegrationBlockType.GOOGLE_CALENDAR,
          }),
      },
    ]);

    await page.goto(/typebots/${typebotId}/edit)
    await page.getByText('Configure...').click()
    await page.fill('input[placeholder="OAuth Client ID"]', ${process.env.CLIENT_ID});
    await page.fill('input[placeholder="Calendar ID"]', 'your-calendar-id');
    await page.fill('input[placeholder="Monday to Friday, 9 AM to 5 PM"]', 'availability-settings');
    // Add additional configuration steps if needed
  });
});
```

but when i try to use the block in the integration tab it gives me the error in the screenshot attached can you please guide me thank you.

[image]

I tried to integrate my google calendar integration schema into integrationBlockType global enum.ts file but whenever i try to access it in the application it crashes down and give me the above mentioned error.